# Expense ratio over time

Tags: asset-returns

I'm trying to reproduce the results in the table below from [this article](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/092613/pay-attention-your-funds-expense-ratio.asp) of Investopedia, but none of my calculations match. What is the correct way to calculate the expense ratio in this case?

[image: Expense ratio table]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, anything on Investopedia needs to be taken with a big grain of salt. (Wikipedia sometimes has correct information, but Investopedia - almost never.)

Let us try to reverse-engineer [Sabrina Jiang](https://www.sabjiang.com/investopedia)'s table on Investopedia.

The first column is easy to reproduce.

We start with 10,000. Every year we earn 10%. So our assets are:

year 1: 10,000.00

year 2: 10,000.00 * 1.1 = 11,000.00

year 3: 11,000.00 * 1.1 = 12,100.00

year 4: 12,100.00 * 1.1 = 13,310.00

year 5: 13,310.00 * 1.1 = 14,641.00

year 6: 14,641.00 * 1.1 = 16,105.10

etc

Now suppose the asset manager charges 0.5% in fees.

We again start with 10,000. Every year we earn 10%, but pay 0.5% in fees, so we actually earn 9.5%. So our assets are:

year 0: 10,000.00

year 1: 10,000.00 * 1.095 = 10,950.00

year 2: 10,950.00 * 1.095 = 11,990.25

year 3: 11,990.25 * 1.095 = 13,129.32

year 4: 13,129.32 * 1.095 = 14,376.61

year 5: 14,376.61 * 1.095 = 15,742.39

etc

Sabrina Jiang's table in Investopedia is very close, but not quite that:

year 0: 10,000.00

year 1: 10,000.00 * 1.095 = 10,950.00

year 2: 10,950.00 * 1.09497716894977 = 11,990.00

year 3: 11,990.00 * 1.09499582985822 = 13,129.00

year 4: 13,129.00 * 1.09490441008455 = 14,375.00

year 5: 14,375.00 * 1.09419130434783 = 15,729.00

etc

As you see, for year 1 she uses the correct return (exactly 9.5%), but for the subsequent years it's off by a small amount.

Let us repeat this exercise for the 1% fee column. Every year we earn 10%, but pay 1% in fees, so we actually earn 9.0%.

Sabrina has:

year 0: 10,000.00

year 1: 10,000.00 * 1.09 = 10,900.00

year 2: 10,900.00 * 1.09 = 11,881.00

year 3: 11,881.00 * 1.0899755912802 = 12,950.00

year 4: 12,950.00 * 1.09003861003861 = 14,116.00

year 5: 14,116.00 * 1.0899688296968 = 15,386.00

As you see, for years 1 and 2 she uses the correct return (exactly 9%), but for the subsequent years it's off again.

I have no idea why. I would guess that Sabrina was just being extra sloppy, rounding where she shouldn't. Looking at the quality of her other work on Investopedia, this seems very likely.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to reproduce the same exact table from Investopedia but was not able to. Below is the result that I reproduced using exactly the same equation given from "@Dimitri Vulis" post. Assuming Expense Ratio is the only fees component and asset growing constantly at 10% for 20 years. Not sure if this table is a correct representation of the return values, but feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

#### Updated table

[image]

#### OLD table

[image: Mutual Fund Fees Calculation - Reproduce]

Comment: In the 1% column each row should be 9% greater than the previous row (because 10 - 1 = 9). What formula are you using?

Comment: @nbbo2 I am not able to find the old table spreadsheet & no longer able to replicate the value. I apologize for that. I have updated the table that I was able to replicate. The formula I used for both old and new tables are as follow ${Fund_{t-1}\times(1+{Rate\:of\:Return}-{Expense\:Ratio})}$

Comment: That looks correct to me.